# Prepend AAC file to MP4 causing audio to get out of sync

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, mp4box, audio-conversion

I have an application that handles the normalizing and combining of audio and video files from many different sources.

All incoming audio is normalized as follows:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "PathToIncommingAudioFile" -acodec aac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 128k -strict experimental ""outputFile.aac"
```

All incoming video is normalized as follows:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "PathToIncommingAudioFile" -s 852x480 -r 30 -aspect 1.775 -b:v 2000000 -vcodec mpeg4 -vf ""scale=iw*min(852/iw\,480 /ih):ih*min(852/iw\,480 /ih),pad=852:480 :(852-iw)/2:(480 -ih)/2"" -acodec aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -strict experimental "outputFile.mp4"
```

Each of these commands (please forgive any bad practices, this is not my area of expertise) works for normalizing the media so it can be played across devices.

---

Other code allows us to successfully merge audio to audio and video to video. However when I attempt to merge the two, the audio gets out of sync.

Here is what I'm doing:

1. First the audio is converted to a video file using a simple PNG image as a placard

   ```
   ffmpeg.exe -loop 1 -shortest -i "image.png" -i "normalized.aac" -s 852x450 -r 30 -aspect 1.775 -b:v 2000000 -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -strict experimental "audioAsVideo.mp4"
   ```
2. Next the videos are attempted to be merged the same way that normally works. (A solution with ffmpeg was not found and this is what currently works, in most cases)

   ```
   mp4box.exe -cat "audioAsVideo.mp4" -cat "normalizedVideo.mp4" -new "CombinedVideo.mp4"
   ```
3. Next to handle some videos that only have one channel audio (like webcams) the following hack/fix was added. It runs on all video to video combines and usually works

   ```
   ffmpeg.exe -i "CombinedVideo.mp4" -c copy -ac 1 "SingleChannelCombinedVideo.mp4"
   ```

If this process is done with an audio and a video, the audio sync of the second file is off.  If this is the audio over the placard it is not a big deal. But if it is the video, it is very distracting.

- Does anyone see anything I have done that could cause this?
- An idea on what to change?
- Perhaps a way of butting a buffer in between the two that would force the sync back?
- A better way of doing it?

Comment: @slhck wouldnt that replace the audio from the video with the new audio? I am not trying to replace any audio just concatenate them, and if one is an audio add a placecard.

Comment: Any reason you're using MPEG-4 Visual video (`mpeg4` in FFmpeg) and not H.264 (`-c:v libx264` in FFmpeg)? So, am I correct that `CombinedVideo` shows the out-of-sync errors?

Comment: At the creation of this feature, i believe it was chosen for compatibility with older devices.  I was not involved in that choice.  Yes you are correct `CombinedVideo` shows the out of sync error